# jQuery, how to use only child handler when it was clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have a simple html:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src"..."/>
      <div>...</div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <img src"..."/>
      <div>...</div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <img src"..."/>
      <div>...</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have a JavaScript (using jQuery) code. In it I have two `click` handlers:  one handler is applied to `<li>` element, and one handler is applied to `<img>` element.

**Question**: How can I use the two handlers separately? I want to use only the `<li>`'s click handler when a user clicks an `<li>`, and only the `<img>`'s handler, when a user clicks an `<img>` tag. How can I implement this via jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `event.stopPropagation` on `img` handler. See below,

```
$('img').click(function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the target from within your `li` handler:

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target).is('img') return;
    // Now run the rest of your code...
});
```